# How to fix mail online status?

Tags: email, catalina, gmail

[image: mail]

Starting with Catalina, my gmail accounts in Mail would randomly give me. It's driving me insane, how do I fix this?

Comment: Use the Connection Doctor to get more info about the problem.

Comment: Same here. This popup happens multiple times per day. Any luck?